# Windows XP, Bluetooth, & accepting files

Tags: windows-xp, bluetooth, file-transfer

I've got a cell phone and hooked it up to my laptop running Windows XP. I can send files from my laptop to my phone and from my phone to my laptop just fine, but only one at a time. Questions:

1. How can I transfer more than 1 file at a time from Windows to my cell phone? I'm using whatever bluetooth client came with XP (SP 3)
2. How can I make XP accept files from my cell phone without having to click on "receive file" first? How can I receive more than one file at a time?

Because going on a trip (which I'm doing frequently at the moment) and transferring 30+ pictures one by one is a huge pain in the rear end.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean you want to queue several files to transfer?

Comment: I want to select n files to transfer. That program that came with XP lets me send only one file at a time to the phone. If I want to receive a file from the phone I have to select "receive file" otherwise Windows won't accept the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a laptop through work now that runs Windows 7. It works under Windows 7 just fine with the same bluetooth adapter. Problem solved.